# ActiveRecord `has_one` association extension method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

I've tried to extend `has_one` association with method:

```
has_one :subscription_plan, -> { where current: true } do
  def in newspaper
    where newspaper: newspaper
  end
end
```

and got an error `undefined method 'in' for #<SubscriptionPlan...>`

But it works with `has_many`:

```
has_many :subscription_plans, -> { where current: true } do
  def in newspaper
    where(newspaper: newspaper).take
  end
end
```

How to make it works with `has_one` on Rails 4.2.1?

Answer (score 0):

By accessing `has_many` association you receive `SubscriptionPlan::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy` but with `has_one` you simply receive `SubscriptionPlan` instance itself.

So there is nothing here to be extended.

If you would provide more information about your models I would help you with exact code.

Comment: thanx a lot! ActiveRecord docs http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-extensions are a bit confusing: `Extensions can refer to the internals of the association proxy using these three attributes of the proxy_association accessor: ... 
proxy_association.target returns the associated object for belongs_to or has_one, or the collection of associated objects for has_many or has_and_belongs_to_many.`. Is it a mistake in docs that `has_one` is mentioned?

Comment: I don't think it's an error but right now I can't comment it =)